# How do I get Stripe's "payment_intent.suceeded" response from the webhook in order to process an order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm running a Vue app with a express server. On the client, I'm using the createPaymentIntent, createPaymentMethod, and the confirmCardPayment apis. The documentation clearly states [Payment Intents, verifying statuses](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/verifying-status)

> Your integration shouldn’t attempt to handle order fulfillment on the client side because it is possible for customers to leave the page after payment is complete but before the fulfillment process initiates. Instead, use webhooks to monitor the payment_intent.succeeded event and handle its completion asynchronously instead of attempting to initiate fulfillment on the client side.

The flow of an order being placed is as follows:

1. An order is created with customer details and products - the newOrder.
2. call createPaymentIntent(newOrder)
3. call stripe.createPaymentMethod({type, card})
4. gather the result from stripe.confirmCardPayment(secret, {payment_method: paymentMethodRequest.paymentMethod.id,
   shipping: billingDetails,})
5. if result.error - show error message to customer on the client
6. else, I handle loading and set successfulPayment = true to trigger actions on the client (animations, etc). And importantly, I call my OrderService.postOrder(newOrder) to send order to backend for processing in Mongo.

```
    async createOrder() {
      this.loading(true);
      this.$v.$touch();
      if (!this.$v.$invalid) {
        // order item details....
        const cardElement = elements.getElement("card");
        const billingDetails = {
          name: user.name,
          address: {
            city: user.city,
            line1: user.street,
            state: "NY"
          },
          phone: user.phone
        };
        try {
          const response = await OrderService.createPaymentIntent(newOrder);

          const secret = response.data.clientSecret;
          this.deliveryFee = response.data.deliveryFee;
          this.totalAmount = response.data.totalAmount;
          const paymentMethodRequest = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: "card",
            card: cardElement

          });
          const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(secret, {
            payment_method: paymentMethodRequest.paymentMethod.id,
            shipping: billingDetails,
            receipt_email: "kevinturney01@gmail.com"
          });

          // ! DO NOT CONFIRM A SUCCESS ON THE CLIENT, RELY ON THE WEBHOOK!!!!!
          // console.log("LINE 443", result, result.error);
          if (result.error) {
            const error = result.error;
            this.showErrorMessage(error);
          } else {
            this.successfullPayment = true;
            this.isLoading = false;
            //! NEED TO REDIRECT TO SUCCESSS PAGE
            OrderService.postOrder(newOrder).catch(error => {
              // https://guillim.github.io/vue/2019/03/20/damn-vuejs-observer.html
              this.updateErrors(Object.assign([], error.response.data.errors));
            });
            console.log("success");
            this.updateOrder(newOrder);

          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
```

My webhook endpoint is pretty much straight from the Stripe docs:

/webhook

```
    static async apiPostWebhookEvent(req, res) {
    let data, eventType
    let paymentIntent
    let event = null
    console.log("HITTING STRIPE WEBHOOK")
    // Check if webhook signing is configured.

    if (process.env.WHSNGROK) { //WHSNGROK hits endpoint
    // Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret.

    let signature = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    console.log("SIGNATURE",signature)
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        req.rawBody,
        signature,
        process.env.WHSNGROK
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);
      return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    data = event.data;
    eventType = event.type;
  } else {
    // Webhook signing is recommended, but if the secret is not configured in `config.js`,
    // we can retrieve the event data directly from the request body.
    data = req.body.data;
    eventType = req.body.type;
    console.log("LINE 38 WEBHOOK", eventType)
    console.log("LINE 39", event.type)
  }
  // event.type || eventType || eventType.type
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.created':
      paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      break;
    case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
      paymentIntent = event.data.object;
payment_intent.payment_failed
      const message = intent.last_payment_error && intent.last_payment_error.message;
      console.log('❌ Payment failed.', paymentIntent.id, message);
      break;
    case 'payment_intent.processing':
      paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      break;
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a function to handle the event payment_intent.succeeded
      // Funds have been captured
      // Fulfill any orders, e-mail receipts, etc
      
      // At this point how do I or can I send the order to MongoDB and get the payment_intent.succeeded confirmation from the webhook to the client?

      console.log(' Payment captured!', paymentIntent.id);
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
    }
  return res.sendStatus(200);
  }
}
```

So to sum up. In the switch/case in the webhook, how can I get the payment_intent.succeeded from the webhook to my client (I understand this is a post request that Stripe is making to my server). That, instead of calling the confirmCardPayment() on the client and relying on that result? Is it possible to call post my newOrder from there or do I still need to call my OrderService.postOrder(newOrder) from the client.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents

[webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to check whether the webhook has hit your server is to either get the client to ping the server to check the order status every X seconds, or you could establish a web-socket connection between the client and server so that the server can push a message to the client telling it that the `paymentIntent` has succeeded (or any other status messages).

Either of those options are fine, although I think it would be safer for the webhook to trigger the update to the Order on the server instead of the client doing that once it receives a response. Otherwise if the connection between the client and the server goes down, then it's possible that the Order will be paid for but not marked as paid and then any other associated actions that the client is meant to carry out will not occur. It's essentially removing any dependency on the client for the Order workflow to be completed once the user has paid for the Order.

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph @KingJ, on the link I posted, verifying status, they talk about polling. "It is technically possible to use polling instead of webhooks to monitor for changes caused by asynchronous operations—repeatedly retrieving a PaymentIntent so that you can check its status—but this is markedly less reliable..." For the second option which I like, how would I transfer/replace the call from my client to post the order, and instead place the order data and the call to post to MongoDB in the "succeeded" case in the webhook?

Comment: My suggestion of polling was for the client polling your server, not the Stripe server, but agreed that a web-socket connection between the client and your server is better. You could just copy whatever code is used to create the Order from the `PostOrder` endpoint into a function that the webhook can trigger when the payment intent succeeds. Then you can replace that call to `OrderService.PostOrder` in the client with the web-socket handling and add the appropriate web-socket handling on the server.

Comment: I kind of get most of what you recommend. From initial research, a websocket on my server doesn't seem too complicated.  Another issue might be, when I call Orderservice.postOrder(newOrder), I have my validation middleware (express-validator) on that route endpoint. So I guess I can move that also.