# How to fulfill orders after Stripe's checkout.session.completed event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, mern

My problem is with Stripe's metadata object having a 500 character limit. I have a working checkout flow but my only restriction is the character limit for my cart. My cartItems object has extras and customer notes I want to include for each cart Item. With that being said, the metadata limit gets to 500 characters fast. I have read on another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69799650/how-do-i-get-stripes-payment-intent-suceeded-response-from-the-webhook-in-ord), implementing websockets into my app which would let me create the order using after listening to stripes event. How would I go about this? Any other workarounds?

```
let endpointSecret;
endpointSecret =
  "whsec_bd73383ed0fcf9cfb27bd4929af341605ad32577dfd8825e1143425b846bb3c3";

router.post("/webhook", (request, response) => {
  const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];

  let data;
  let eventType;

  if (endpointSecret) {
    let event;

    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        request.rawBody,
        sig,
        endpointSecret
      ); 
    } catch (err) {
      response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
      return;
    }

    data = event.data.object;
    eventType = event.type;
  } else {
    data = request.body.data.object;
    eventType = request.body.type;
  }

  // Handle the event
  if (eventType === "checkout.session.completed") {
    stripe.customers
      .retrieve(data.customer)
      .then((customer) => {
        console.log("customer:", customer);
        console.log("data:", data);
        createOrder(customer, data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't typically pass all cart information in metadata, you would typically store that information in your own database and then retrieve the necessary information based on a UUID that corresponds with that data and the order ID that you set on the Checkout Session via metadata which then gets returned via the Webhook.

To give an example of what I'm recommending above --

In your database you would have something like:

| Order ID | Cart Item1 | Cart Item1 Description | Cart Item2... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | hat | red | scarf |
| 123457 | sock | blue |  |

Then when you create your Checkout Session you just pass your Order ID as metadata. When you receive your `checkout.session.completed` Webhook, that metadata will indicate the Order ID so now you have all your data necessary for fulfillment and reconciliation (and you can update your database accordingly).

Also, to clear up a misconception, with [Stripe's metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata) you can have 50 keys each with values up to 500 characters long.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! Definitely cleared things up for me. So do you suggest having the order created first and once you pass the order ID in the webhook update it accordingly? Such as a status of paid?

Comment: Yep exactly the order should already be created by the time the Checkout Session is created and then updated upon receiving the completed Webhook.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again for your solution. I was able to do exactly as you suggested and it even helped me learn more while figuring all that out.